# Issue with UI Conversion Robot - 'str' object not callable / lambda ceased to work / Tkinter Py3

Tags: python, function, object, tkinter, error-handling

I am creating a GUI that calculates currency exchange and need of specific documents.
The flow should be the following

1. Select country from Listbox
   1.1. Insert input (would be string, because input will include comma as separator for k)

- At the click of "Calculate"...

2. Input is converted into float
3. Country value is used to retrieve currency and clip limit on dictionary.
4. The input is converted in USD if needed >> Part of the output in box on the right
5. Value is compared to clip level and will return if ABOVE / BELOW >> Part of the output in box on right

I have been trying to fix the issue tackling it from multiple angles. For instance I found hard to create a set of functions that could cooperate. As I am a beginner, I have troubles to understand how classes works. On the current code, the issue I have is that the conversion of the input from string to float does not work. I have tried several ways and below is my final code (I've simplified some parts).
I am attaching also the design of the robot and the errors.

```
"""SHW CLIP LIMIT GUI"""

#Lists and dictionaries for the GUI
countries = ['Czech-Republic', 'Estonia', 'Poland', 'Romania']

cliplimit = {'Czech-Republic': 100000, 'Estonia': 500000, 'Poland': 200000, 'Romania': 50000}

currencies = {'Czech-Republic': 'CZK', 'Poland': 'PLN', 'Estonia':'EUR'}


#The GUI itself:

from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
# add widgets here

window.title('SHW Clip & Currency Converter')
window.geometry("450x560+10+20")

"""INPUT FIELD MEASUREMENTS"""
x1 = 20
y1 = 500

#This is the input field
txtfld=Entry(window, text="This is Entry Widget", bd=5)
txtfld.place(x=x1, y=y1-30)


#This is for the list of countries
list=Listbox(window, height=20, selectmode='single')

list.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH)
for country in countries:
    list.insert(END,country)
list.place(x=20, y=100)


#Message box for output only
output=Text(window, height=5, width=25)
output.place(x=200, y=100)
```

Problems must be from here on:

```
#This is to display output in big textbox

def robot():
    """Function of Robot is to analyze input and release output message in textbox."""
    country = list.get(ACTIVE)
    clip = cliplimit.get(country)
    inputvalue = txtfld.get()

    def floatize(): #TRANSFORM INPUT VALUE INTO FLOAT >>> I guess the issue is here.
        clearvalue = inputvalue.replace(","," ")
        cleanvalue = float(clearvalue)
        roundvalue = round(cleanvalue,2)
        return roundvalue

    def curcheck(): #CURRENCY CHECKER
        if country in currencies.keys():
            curname = currencies.get(country)
        else:
            curname = "USD"
        return curname

    def converter(): #CURRENCY RATE EXCHANGE
        if country == "Poland":
            return round(floatize() / 3, 2)
        elif country == "Czech-Republic":
            return round(floatize() / 20, 2)
        else:
            return round(floatize(), 2)

    def clipchecker(): #CHECK IF ABOVE/BELOW CLIP LEVEL
        if floatize() >= clip:
            print('Value ', inputvalue(), clip, 'is ABOVE clip level - EU PO required.')
        else:
            print ('Value ', inputvalue(), clip, 'is BELOW clip level.')


    result = ['Original value:', inputvalue, curcheck(), 'is equal to: ', converter(), 'USD. \n',
          clipchecker()]

    output.delete(0,END) #was originally working with another script, but gives error only
    output.insert(0,result) #same as above


#Button to be programmed - calculates
btn=Button(window, text="Calculate", fg='black', command= lambda:robot())
btn.place(x=x1, y=y1)
```

"""FROM HERE THERE ARE NO ISSUES"""

```
#Copy button
def copy_text():
    txt = output.get()
    print (txt)
    copycomment.clipboard_append(txt) #Copies Output to Clipboard
    copycomment.update()
    copycomment.clipboard_clear()

copycomment = Button(window, text="Copy Output", fg='black', command = copy_text)
copycomment.place(x=255, y=200)



window.mainloop()
```

[image: Original Design]
[image: Errors in Pycharm]

Comment: Remove the `()` from `inputvalue()` and try again.

Comment: That error seems pretty self-explanatory. `inputvalue` is a string, and you're trying to call it as if it was a function.

Comment: @Atlas435 @BryanOakley -
That did not solve the issue, was something I've tried before and I get a different error, where comma cannot be removed from the value given: 
    `clearvalue = inputvalue.replace(","," ") \\
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'replace' `

Comment: It sounds like you're using `inputvalue` as a string in some code and as a function in others. You need to be consistent.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am sorry but I don't seem to understand where the problem is :( I found some places where inputvalue was as function >> `inputvalue()` and I fixed that but I keep receiving the very same error. I will review the errors and the code and I will later update once more the query with partial solution or if the issue continues. Meanwhile thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to sort the code differently.
Instead of creating multiple functions, I worked around the original input to achieve outputs in logical succession.

The function

```
    """BEGINNING OF OUTPUT CREATION"""

def truerobot():
    """Function of Robot is to analyze input and release output message in textbox."""
    country = list.get(ACTIVE)
    input = txtfld.get()
    clip = cliplimit.get(country)
    currency = currencies.get(country)

    if currency == None:
        truecur = "USD"
    else:
        truecur = currency

    inputnocomma = float(input.replace(",",""))

    if country == "Poland":
        convertedinput = round(inputnocomma/15,2)
    elif country == "Czech-Republic":
        convertedinput = round(inputnocomma/1.5,2)
    else:
        convertedinput = round(inputnocomma,2)

    finaloutput = "{:,}".format(convertedinput)

    if inputnocomma >= clip:
        cliptext = " is ABOVE clip level. EU PO is required."
    else:
        cliptext = " is BELOW clip level."

    output.insert(INSERT,"The conversion of "+input+" "+truecur+" is: "+finaloutput+" USD. \n"+input+" "+truecur+cliptext+"\n \nCountry Selected: "+country)

    #Create text comment!
    commentoutput = "The conversion of "+input+" "+truecur+" is: "+finaloutput+" USD. \n"+input+" "+truecur+cliptext
    truerobot.variable = str(commentoutput)

    """END OF OUTPUT CREATION"""
```

The resulting outputs will be:

- the one displayed on a textbox
- the one that can be copied on clipboard (truerobot.variable)

This way, the same output can be also used when the textbox is not an Entry() object.

That is because I found out that the content of a textbox created with Entry() can be copied to the clipboard, but not one of a Text() object. It does fine as workaround.